# comma separated names based on company ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have following table of Employee details

```
EmployeeName   CompayId    CompanyLastActive
---------------------------------------------------------
robort          112        10 Jun 2015 09:30 
john            113        11 Jun 2015 11:10
sunny           114        14 Jun 2015 16:10
sumanth         114        15 Jun 2015 18:11
usha            115        07 Jun 2015 13:14
sudheer         115        14 Jun 2015 17:10
sweety          115        08 Jun 2015 16:34
```

I need to get the latest employee active time based on CompanyID with Comma separated EmployeeName like below

```
EmployeeName           CompayId        CompanyLastActive
---------------------------------------------------------
robort                 112               10 Jun 2015 09:30 
john                   113               11 Jun 2015 11:10
sunny, sumanth         114               15 Jun 2015 18:11        
usha, sudheer, sweety   115               14 Jun 2015 17:10
```

please help me how to solve.

Comment: are you using all 3 version of sql server?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I was in that room too. This question is a bit different from that one. Here OP wants different **records** in one line, whereas, in that question, OP was trying to get multiple **columns** in one (excluding NULL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT EmployeeName = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + e1.EmployeeName
          FROM dbo.Employee e1
          WHERE e.CompayId = e1.CompayId
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
        e.CompayId,
        MAX(CompanyLastActive) as CompanyLastActive
FROM dbo.Employee e
GROUP BY e.CompayID
ORDER BY e.CompayId
```

Result:

```
EmployeeName        CompayId    CompanyLastActive
-------------------------------------------------------
robort              112         June, 10 2015 09:30:00
john                113         June, 11 2015 11:10:00
sunny,sumanth       114         June, 15 2015 18:11:00
usha,sudheer,sweety 115         June, 14 2015 17:10:00
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab1f1/13).

Answer (score 3):

Check this out, i have not checked this as i'm feeling lazy to build schema, it would probably throw group by error, You can handle it

```
SELECT 
  Results.CompayId,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + CAST(EmployeeName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE (ID = Results.ID) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS NameValues
  ,max(Results.CompanyLastActive) as CompanyLastActive
FROM YourTable Results
GROUP BY CompayId
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT EmployeeNames = dbo.EmployeeNamesPerCompany(CompanyID,', '), 
       CompanyID, 
       CompanyLastActive = MAX(CompanyLastActive)
FROM Employee e
GROUP BY CompanyID
ORDER BY MAX(CompanyLastActive)
```

If you have created a scalar valued function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[EmployeeNamesPerCompany]
(
    @companyID Int,
    @delimiter varchar(5)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
    SELECT   @Names = COALESCE(@Names + @delimiter, '') + e.EmployeeName
    FROM    Employee e
    WHERE e.CompanyId = @companyID
    ORDER BY e.EmployeeName
    return @Names
END
```

<kbd>[**Sql-Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b48a6/6/0)</kbd>